# rearrange getopt output, such that a specific argument executes first every time (if given)

Tags: bash, shell, getopt

Is there any way to rearrange the getopt.

Look at the simple script which uses gnu getopt.

```
#!/bin/bash
TEMP=`getopt -o abc -n 'test.sh' -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$TEMP"

while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -a) echo "alpha"   ;shift ;;
        -b) echo "bravo"   ;shift ;
        -c) echo "charlie" ;shift ;;
        -d) echo "delta"    ;shift ;;
        --) shift ; break ;;
        *) echo "error!" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
```

Outputs:

```
$./alpha-project -c -a -b 
  charlie
  alpha
  bravo


$./alpha-project -b -c -a
  bravo
  charlie
  alpha
```

Desired output:

```
$./alpha-project -c -a -b 
  alpha
  charlie
  bravo


$./alpha-project -b -c -a
  alpha
  bravo
  charlie
```

Now, No matter where the -a is placed in the arguments, the -a case must be executed first.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to explicitly rearrange the positional parameters like below

```
#!/bin/bash
# Say you want '-a' to be first every time
temp="$( getopt -o abc -n 'test.sh' -- "$@" )"
temp="$(sed -E ':l1;s/(-[^a]) (-a)/\2 \1/g;/-[^a] -a/bl1' <<< "$temp")" #re-arrangement part


while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -a) echo "alpha"   ;shift ;;
        -b) echo "bravo"   ;shift ;; # A semicolon is missing in question
        -c) echo "charlie" ;shift ;;
        -d) echo "delta"    ;shift ;;
        --) shift ; break ;;
        *) echo "error!" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
```

This will give you the desired results.

**Sample Runs**

```
# ./40978894 -b -a -c -a
alpha
alpha
bravo
charlie
# ./40978894 -b -a -c
alpha
bravo
charlie
# ./40978894 -b -a -c -a -a
alpha
alpha
alpha
bravo
charlie
```

Note that the replacement does some heavy-lifting as well managing inputs like `-b -a -c -a -a`. For more complex cases involving values for positional parameters, you need more complex replacements.

---

<sup>**Caveat :** Use lowercase for user variables ie TEMP -> temp</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> First time you can parse the -a and after the others.

```
#!/bin/bash
TEMP=`getopt -o abc -n 'test.sh' -- "$@"`

eval set -- "$TEMP"
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -a) echo "alpha"   ;break ;;
        -b|-c|-d) shift ;;
        *)  break ;;
    esac
done

eval set -- "$TEMP"
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -a) shift ;;
        -b) echo "bravo"   ;shift ;;
        -c) echo "charlie" ;shift ;;
        -d) echo "delta"    ;shift ;;
        --) shift ; break ;;
        *) echo "error!" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be doing any actions in the option parsing loop. You should just set up variables/config so that the rest of the program does what it's supposed to do. When you do that, your ordering problem disappears.

If you look at the [getopt source code](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/misc-utils/getopt.c?h=stable/v2.28#n402), you'll see that even the tool itself does this internally. No operations are performed in the option loop, it only sets up variables and data structures for the rest of the program.

You can do the same:

```
#!/bin/bash
temp=`getopt -o abc -n 'test.sh' -- "$@"`
eval set -- "$temp"

alpha=""
bravo=""
charlie=no
while true ; do
    case "$1" in
        -a) alpha=1     ;shift ;;
        -b) bravo=1     ;shift ;;
        -c) charlie=yes ;shift ;;
        --) shift ; break ;;
        *) echo "error!" ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

if [[ -n "$alpha" ]]
then
  echo "Doing alpha (charlie: $charlie)"
fi

if [[ -n "$bravo" ]]
then
  echo "Doing bravo (charlie: $charlie)"
fi
```

Here's what happens when you run it:

```
$ ./testscript -b -a -c
Doing alpha (charlie: yes)
Doing bravo (charlie: yes)

$ ./testscript -ab
Doing alpha (charlie: no)
Doing bravo (charlie: no)
```